# expliquenme la razon de invalid syntax por favor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

estoy desarrollando mi proyecto final pero ahora por ninguna razon aparente me lanza syntax erro en el prefijo impo- de un import

```
import sys
import requests
^^^^(aqui me dice que error por ninguna razon aparente)
import json
import marshal
import webbrowser
from string import Template
```

Comment: olvidenlo ya resolvi

Comment: Si crees que tu solución pueda ser útil a otros, puedes auto-responderte. Si en cambio era un error tonto y no merece la pena la respuesta, puedes borrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que el error sea por el  import requests que viene con la instalación predeterminada de python si trabajas con linux este es el comando 
$ sudo pip install requests si tiene  pip instalado.
Saludos.